# line chart won't appear

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 types of expenses and would like to create 3 line chart against the year but the line chart is not appearing.

[image: output]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = np.genfromtxt("Expenses.csv",
    delimiter=',',skip_header=1,
    dtype=[('year','i8'),('Type','U8'), ('Amount','i8')],missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])
print (d)
x_rent = d[d['Type']=='rental']['year']
y_rent = d[d['Type']=='rental']['Amount']
x_salary = d[d['Type']=='salaries']['year']
y_salary = d[d['Type']=='salaries']['Amount']
x_others = d[d['Type']=='others']['year']
y_others = d[d['Type']=='others']['Amount']
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(x_rent, y_rent, c='b',  label='rental')
ax1.plot(x_salary,y_salary, c='r', label='salaries')
ax1.plot(x_others,y_others, c='g', label='Others')
plt.title('Expenses incurred',fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.legend(loc='upper right');

plt.show()
```

Sample of my data

[image: data]

Can someone advise where I have done wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

**First check your data file** (i.e. open Expenses.csv with notepad).

**Then check the result of `print(d)`**. This is what your code is going to try to plot.

In your python code:

Change `('Amount','i8')` to (say) `('Amount','f8')`. You are reading floating-point values, not integers.

Change `d['Type']=='others' to d['Type']=='Others'`. String comparison is case sensitive.

Once that is working you may have to think about how/where you write the year labels on your graph (see below for your test data).

[image]

Test data:

```
Financial_year,Type,Amount
2022,rental,236105.3
2022,salaries,836752.4
2022,Others,6900.0
2021,rental,217438.0
2021,salaries,557919.8
2021,Others,2600
2020,rental,201930.2
2020,salaries,502791.1
2020,Others,0
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have revised the code as per your suggestion but the line charts are still not appearing.

Comment: @unleasehed, I have added the output graph to my answer. The data is the limited amount that you gave. The lines are clearly there.

Comment: Note that you do print out `d` in your code - use that to check that (a) your data file exists as a distinct file (and not just in Excel) and (b) your code reads it correctly. I have added the file that I tested it with to my answer.

Comment: @ lastchance
I did manage to print out my data but the line chart is still not showing.

Comment: What was the result of print(d)? Does it correspond to your data file? Check, in particular, the "Amount" column. Your original question shows what you would get for a file with no data.

Comment: Print out also the arrays x_rent, y_rent etc.